# dataLayer.push does not fire a request

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to push an event to my google tag manger datalayer, I don't understand why
`dataLayer.push({'event': 'click'});` involve a post request to
`https://www.google-analytics.com/collect but`  dataLayer.push({'event': 'test'});` does not involve a request?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Okay, see my (unaccepted) answer here: [When does data get sent to google after dataLayer.push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760514/when-does-data-get-sent-to-google-after-datalayer-push/59771044#59771044)

In a nutshell, pushing data to the datalayer does not by itself fire any requests, since (unless you explicity have set up server-side GTM, but then you wouldn't be asking such questions) GTM is a client-side javascript. Pushing data to GTM with an "event" key just make the data available to the triggers and tags configured in GTM.

So presumably, your GA tag has a click trigger attached, but not "custom event" trigger that responds to your custom event called "test". If you want a GA tag to be send, you would have to create the trigger and add it to your GA tag.

Comment: Thank you so so mush. Any idea How to Create a trigger and add it to your GA tag ?